# Idris: function works with Nat parameter and fails type checking with Integer parameter

Tags: idris, partial-functions

I am new to Idris. I am experimenting with types and my task is to make an "onion": a function that takes two arguments: a number and whatever and puts whatever into `List` nested such number of times.

For example, the result for `mkOnion 3 "Hello World"` should be `[[["Hello World"]]]`.
I've made such a function, this is my code:

```hs
onionListType : Nat -> Type -> Type
onionListType Z b = b
onionListType (S a) b = onionListType a (List b)

mkOnionList : (x : Nat) -> y -> onionListType x y 
mkOnionList Z a = a
mkOnionList (S n) a = mkOnionList n [a]

prn : (Show a) => a -> IO (); 
prn a = putStrLn $ show a;

main : IO()
main = do
    prn $ mkOnionList 3 4
    prn $ mkOnionList 2 'a'
    prn $ mkOnionList 5 "Hello"
    prn $ mkOnionList 0 3.14
```

The result of program work:

> ```
> [[[4]]]  
> [['a']]  
> [[[[["Hello"]]]]]  
> 3.14
> ```

This is exactly what I need.
But when I do the same, but change Nat to Integer like this

```hs
onionListTypeI : Integer -> Type -> Type
onionListTypeI 0 b = b
onionListTypeI a b = onionListTypeI (a-1) (List b)

mkOnionListI : (x : Integer) -> y -> onionListTypeI x y 
mkOnionListI 0 a = a
mkOnionListI n a = mkOnionListI (n-1) [a]
```

I get an error:

> ```
> When checking right hand side of mkOnionListI with expected type   
>     onionListTypeI 0 y
>
> Type mismatch between  
>     y (Type of a) and   
>     onionListTypeI 0 y (Expected type)
> ```

Why does type checking fails?

I think this is because `Integer` can take negative values and `Type` can't be computed in case of negative values. If I am right, how does the compiler understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that the type can't be computed. But that is because the `onionListTypeI` is not total. You can check this in the REPL

```
*test> :total onionListTypeI
Main.onionListTypeI is possibly not total due to recursive path:
    Main.onionListTypeI, Main.onionListTypeI
```

(Or even better, demanding `%default total` in the source code, which would raise an error.)

Because the type constructor is not total, the compiler won't normalize `onionListTypeI 0 y` to `y`. It is not total, because of the case `onionListTypeI a b = onionListTypeI (a-1) (List b)`. The compiler does only know that subtracting 1 from an `Integer` results to an `Integer`, but not which number exactly (unlike when doing it with a `Nat`). This is because arithmetic with `Integer`, `Int`, `Double` and the various `Bits` are defined with primary functions like `prim__subBigInt`. And if these functions wouldn't be blind, the compiler should have a problem with negative values, like you assumed.