# Idris: arithmetics for bounded Double

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I am new to Idris. I need to create a data describing a bounded number. So I've made such data with such a constructor:

```
data BoundedDouble : (a, b : Double) -> Type where
  MkBoundedDouble : (x : Double) -> 
                    {auto p : a <= x && x <= b = True} -> 
                    BoundedDouble a b
```

It seems to create a `Double` between `a` and `b`.
And here is a simple example of use:

```
test : BoundedDouble 0.0 1.0
test = MkBoundedDouble 0.0
```

It works. But now I want to implement `Num` interface for `BoundedDouble`. I tried this:

```
Num (BoundedDouble a b) where
  (MkBoundedDouble x) + (MkBoundedDouble y) = 
    MkBoundedDouble (ifThenElse (x + y > b) 
                      (x + y - (b - a))
                      (ifThenElse (x + y < a)
                        (x + y + (b - a))
                        (x + y)))
```

But it doesn't work, I guess why, but I can't explain it. 
How should I implement the addition?

I don't know exactly what should I do or read to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. [`Double` arithmetic is defined with primitive functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479512/idris-function-works-with-nat-parameter-and-fails-type-checking-with-integer-pa) Idris can't even proof that `a <= b = True -> b <= c = True -> a <= c = True` (which, by the way, does not even hold all the time - so this is not Idris' fault.) There is no proof for `a <= b = True` other then just checking it, what you tried with the `ifThenElse`.

When working with such blind run-time proofs (so just `… = True`), [`Data.So`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/base_doc/docs/Data.So.html) is quite helpful. `ifThenElse (a <= x) … …` branches off given a boolean check, but the code in the branches does not know about result of the check. With `choose (a <= x)` you get the result for the branches, with `Left prf` and `prf : So (a <= x)` or `Right prf` and `prf : So (not (a <= x))`.

I suppose if the result of adding two bounded doubles would be bigger then the upper bound, the result should be this upper bound. Lets make a first attempt:

```
import Data.So

data BoundedDouble : (a, b : Double) -> Type where
    MkBoundedDouble : (x : Double) 
                      -> {auto high : So (a <= x)}
                      -> {auto low : So (x <= b)}
                      -> BoundedDouble a b

Num (BoundedDouble a b) where
    (+) (MkBoundedDouble u) (MkBoundedDouble v) =
           let x = u + v
           in case (choose (a <= x), choose (x <= b)) of
             (Left _, Left _) => MkBoundedDouble x
             (Right _, _) => ?holeMin
             (_, Right _) => ?holeMax
```

This already typechecks, but has holes in it. We want to set `?holeMin` to `MkBoundedDouble a` and `?holeMax` to `MkBoundedDouble b`. However, `MkBoundedDouble` right now needs two proofs: `high` and `low`. In the case of `?holeMax` those would be with `x = b` `So (a <= b)` and `So (b <= b)`. Again, Idris does not know that `b <= b` for every `b : Double`. So we would need to choose again to get these proofs:

```
             (_, Right _) => case (choose (a <= b), choose (b <= b)) of
                  (Left _, Left _) => MkBoundedDouble b
                  _ => ?what
```

Because Idris cannot see that `b <= b`, the function would be partial. We could cheat and use for example `MkBoundedDouble u` in `?what`, so the function will typecheck and hope that this will indeed never occur.

There is also the possibility to convince the type checker with force that `b <= b` is always true:

```
data BoundedDouble : (a, b : Double) -> Type where
    MkBoundedDouble : (x : Double) 
                      -> {auto rightSize : So (a <= b)}
                      -> {auto high : So (a <= x)}
                      -> {auto low : So (x <= b)}
                      -> BoundedDouble a b

DoubleEqIsSym : (x : Double) -> So (x <= x) 
DoubleEqIsSym x = believe_me (Oh)

Num (BoundedDouble a b) where
    (+) (MkBoundedDouble u) (MkBoundedDouble v) =
           let x = u + v
           in case (choose (a <= x), choose (x <= b)) of
             (Left _, Left _) => MkBoundedDouble x
             (Right _, _) => MkBoundedDouble a {high=DoubleEqIsSym a}
             (_, Right _) => MkBoundedDouble b {low=DoubleEqIsSym b}
```

Or we could be even safer and put the proofs for the upper and lower bounds in the data constructor, so we can use them in `?holeMin` and `?holeMax`. This would be:

```
import Data.So

data BoundedDouble : (a, b : Double) -> Type where
    MkBoundedDouble : (x : Double) 
                      -> {auto rightSize : So (a <= b)}
                      -> {auto leftId : So (a <= a)}
                      -> {auto rightId : So (b <= b)}
                      -> {auto high : So (a <= x)}
                      -> {auto low : So (x <= b)}
                      -> BoundedDouble a b

Num (BoundedDouble a b) where
    (+) (MkBoundedDouble u) (MkBoundedDouble v) =
           let x = u + v
           in case (choose (a <= x), choose (x <= b)) of
             (Left _, Left _) => MkBoundedDouble x
             (Right _, _) => MkBoundedDouble a
             (_, Right _) => MkBoundedDouble b
```

You see that even that the constructor is packed with proofs, they don't complicate the implementation. And they should get erased in the actual run-time code.

However, as an exercise you could try to implement `Num` for

```
data BoundedDouble : (a, b : Double) -> Type where
    MkBoundedDouble : (x : Double)
                      -> {auto rightSize : So (a <= b)}
                      -> {auto high : So (a <= x)}
                      -> {auto low : So (x <= b)} 
                      -> BoundedDouble a b
    Min : {auto rightSize : So (a <= b)} -> BoundedDouble a b
    Max : {auto rightSize : So (a <= b)} -> BoundedDouble a b
```

Sadly, there aren't many resources for Idris yet. Besides the tutorial there is [a book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) in development, that I would recommend. It gives more approachable exercises than working with primitive types. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very helpful! But can you please explain one more time, why do we need the proofs ```So (b <= b) ``` and ```So (a <= a)```?

Comment: @O.Phillips, because there is NaN: `let nan=0.0/0.0 in nan /= nan`