# Can't index into a list constructed by a recursive function

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, idris

I have a function `getN'` that is supposed to construct a list of n elements recursively, however I think I'm doing something wrong because I can't index into it and the output looks unexpected:

```
getN' : (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Int -> List Double
getN' f dt t0 y0 0 = []
getN' f dt t0 y0 n = rk4' :: getN' f dt (t0+dt) rk4' (n-1) where
    rk4' = rk4 f dt t0 y0
```

The output of `getN' f 0.1 0 1 100` is:

```
1.0050062486962987 :: getN' f 0.1 0.1 1.0050062486962987 99 : List Double
```

Which looks unfamiliar to me. Specifically the syntax head::tail is familiar, but Idris usually prints out the entire result in the REPL, which suggests something isn't right in this instance.

The output of `index 0 $ getN' f 0.1 0 1 100` is:

```
(input):1:9:When checking argument ok to function Prelude.List.index:
        Can't find a value of type
                InBounds 0 (getN' f 0.1 0.0 1.0 100)
```

What am I doing/getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getN'` isn't total, so the REPL doesn't evaluate the recursive call (as it could loop forever). Set `%default total` or `total getN' : …` to get a warning from the compiler, or check in the REPL with `:total getN'`. Idris can't reason about `Int`, and in this particular case, `getN' f 0.1 0 1 -1` wouldn't stop.

If you replace `Int` with `Nat` it works (with `0` to `Z`, `n` to `(S n)` and `n - 1` to `n`). From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37490815/5786950): The compiler does only know that subtracting 1 from an `Integer` results to an `Integer`, but not which number exactly (unlike when doing it with a `Nat`). This is because arithmetic with `Integer`, `Int`, `Double` and the various `Bits` are defined with primary functions like `prim__subBigInt`.

Why `index` fails: it needs a proof `InBounds k xs`, that the list has at least `k` elements. In Haskell, `!!` is weaker, and thus can crash at runtime: `(getN' f 0.1 0 1 100) !! 101` would compile, but will throw an exception. This can't happen in Idris:

```
>:t index
Prelude.List.index : (n : Nat) -> (xs : List a) -> {auto ok : InBounds n xs} ->  a

>:printdef InBounds
data InBounds : Nat -> List a -> Type where
  InFirst : InBounds 0 (x :: xs)
  InLater : InBounds k xs -> InBounds (S k) (x :: xs)
```

`auto` means, that the compiler tries to search for a proof `ok : InBounds n xs`. But, again, it doesn't evaluate `getN' …`, so it doesn't find (or even searches) for a proof. That's the error you are getting: `Can't find a value of type InBounds …`

Comment: Excellent I get it! If you could go into a bit more detail as to how the equivalent code in Haskell does work as expected that'd be great